# How can i add list items and heading together, in the below code i don't see li at all

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

### {{ apos.area(data.page, 'body', { widgets: { 'apostrophe-images': { size: 'full' }, 'apostrophe-rich-text': { toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink','Table' ], styles: [ { name: 'Heading', element: 'h3' }, { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' }, { name: 'Listitems', element: 'li' } ] } } }) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add lists to a rich text widget you want to add `'NumberedList'` or `'BulletedList'` to the toolbar array in your configuration.

Your code would look like

```
{{ apos.area(data.page, 'body', { 
  widgets: { 
    'apostrophe-images': { size: 'full' },
    'apostrophe-rich-text': { 
      toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Table', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList' ], 
      styles: [
        { name: 'Heading', element: 'h3' },
        { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' }
      ] 
    }
  }
}) }}
```